# Как подстроить ширину под самое большое слово внутри?

Tags: html, javascript, css

У меня есть некоторые элементы на странице, ширина которых слишком мала, чтобы уместить слово. В итоге получается такая ерунда:

[image]

Мне надо расширить этот элемент так, чтобы в нём небыло разрывов. Т.е.:

[image]

p.s. ширина фиксированная, задаётся в px

Comment: можно кусок кода?, В моем div-е все отлично расширяется до одного слова.

Comment: @IVsevolod по максимуму сохранил оригинальное: http://jsfiddle.net/SdPSW/

Comment: @danpetruk лады, сейчас помучаю код :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как на счет такого, немного костыль, но все же: [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/SdPSW/2/)

```
<div><span>ВЕЧЕРНИЕ НОВОСТИ</span></div>

div {
    width: 1px;
}
span {  
    display:inline-block;
    word-break: normal;
}
```

т.е. основная ширина будет у span-а )

Answer (score 0):

[вот](http://jsfiddle.net/HWAfZ/) css `word-wrap: normal`

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  word-wrap: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<div>Вечерние носки</div>
```

Comment: Есть проблема: текст лишь вылезет за рамки, но div не расширится. http://jsfiddle.net/FXwsU/

Comment: так вы же ее сами задаете